# QVTO - Import Works in 3.4 but not in 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, transformation, m2m, qvt

in my eclipse plugin project the line

```
import transforms.Helper;
```

fails when using version 3.6, but works fine on 3.4. It breaks with the msg:

```
Cannot find imported compilation unit 'transforms.Helper'
```

The file is located in a different Project which defines the following extension points in the plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.runtime.qvtTransformation">
      <transformation
            file="transforms/Helper.qvto"
            id="NameHelper">
      </transformation>
      <transformation
            file="transforms/AssertHelper.qvto"
            id="AssertHelper">
      </transformation>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.runtime.qvtTransformationContainer">
      <sourceContainer
            path="transforms">
      </sourceContainer>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Is this a wellknown error? I couldn't find anything using google. If i can supply any other files/infos to help track the error down, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boys over at:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494274
found the solution. The newer version is less lenient in accepting malformed setups. Correct would be:

```
import NameHelper;
```

just the id, no folder